# How to send start bit manually?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, byte

I am trying to send a byte array to an elettric card via bluetooth and i need to send it with the start bit. i didn't find the way to do this. The card follows a specific protocol that needs a start bit before any information we send.

I need to send this byte array of 7 elements:

```
byte[] data = {0X07, 0x3f, 0x01, 'b', 0x01, 0x08, 0x4e};
mConnection.transmit(data);
```

I've tried to do this to solve the problem but it didn't work:

```
byte[] data = {0x00, 0X07, 0x3f, 0x01, 'b', 0x01, 0x08, 0x4e};
mConnection.transmit(data);
```

or this:

```
byte[] startBit = {0x00};
byte[] data = {0X07, 0x3f, 0x01, 'b', 0x01, 0x08, 0x4e};
mConnection.transmit(startBit); 
mConnection.transmit(data);
```

I tested the info I'm sending via an oscilloscope. When I send info correctly the oscilloscope doesn't see the start bit, but in the above cases the oscilloscope sees the 0 i'm sending as null. I don't know why.

Could it be that the start bit is composed by 7 bits at 0? In this case how can i send 7 bits?

Or my question remains to how can i send a start bit manually before the array I'm sending?

Comment: Hey @Gian9751 even I had this same issue. I was sending 20 character string which would essentially become 20 separate byte characters. But the first character was mysteriously vanishing. I followed the second method you described i.e., to use a random first character. Following that I sent the next 20 characters.

Comment: What is *elettric card*? What kind of device are you using that allows you to observe the signal with an ossiloscope? What kind of instance is `mConnection`? Do you need to send a start *bit* or start *byte*? Can link to a documentation of the protocol?